# Storing the job criteria in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a web portal which will store the job requirement like, experience, salary etc in a database and whenever any user (new/old) matches that  criteria the job should display him in his dashboard after he logins.
My Columns in employees are
Age, City, Industry, Marital status.

So, when admin post the jobs, he will define the criteria which user can see this. For ex. Age between 20-30, City only Mumbai like that.

How do I store these information in database efficiently.

I am using PHP/MySQL.

Comment: You might get more responses if you explain the various options that you've considered. We can then tell you the pros/cons of each.

Comment: This question is too vague.  Read a book on how to develop applications with php/mysql

Comment: Eh, he doesn't seem to vote up or accept answers either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would ideally create a table with the user's:

- Unique ID
- Name
- Marital Status
- City
- Age

Create a second table to pair industry and UUID, like so:

- Unique ID
- Industry

This is so that a given user can belong to more than a single industry.

Third, create a table to pair user IDs and experience:

- Unique ID
- Position
- Industry
- Start date
- End date

Since industry and experience are data which a given user can possess an arbitrary quantity of, you need to abstract the data into its own tables.  Don't try representing all of this information in a single table - it's a solution that scales poorly past a single employer.

I'd also like to note that if your application is going to be deployed in the United States and several other nations, it's actually illegal for employers to discriminate based on age and marital status.  I'm assuming this doesn't apply to you, but there it is.

Answer (score 1):

in terms of speeding up your look ups, the most important thing you'll want to do is make sure you index the columns that you will be searching against.

So for instance, if you want to do a search that is based on someonen's start date:

like:
select * from tablename where start_date > 'some date';

then it's very important that you index the start_date column on the 'tablename' table.

Apart from making sure that your tables are orthongal deciding what the best way of setting up your database you'll want to ask your self what kind of questions will you be asking your database and design your tables around those questions.